# Javascript regex alphanumeric and hyphen C#.net

Tags: javascript, .net, regex, validation, debugging

I have Javascript code  that validates if a field allowd only alphanumeric and hyphens. The problem I am having is that when I run it in debug mode on VisualStudio it works as expected. On the server it does not happen however. I have other regex Javascript code that runs fine, so I don't see how it could be server or personal PC settings.

.Net

```
<asp: TextBox ID="txtBox1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Statuc" onkeyup="validateANdash(this)"></asp:TextBox>
```

Javascript :

```
function validateANdash(field) {
    var value = field.value;
    var reg = /[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/;
    var newVal = reg.test(value) 

    if (newVal == true) {
       alert("This field can only contain alphanumeric values and hyphens. ") ;
       field.value = value.replace(reg, " ") ;
   } 
}
```

I have also tried the regex statement as this with the same results.

```
var reg = /[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$/;
```

Comment: Is `validateANdash` function called on server ?

Comment: Mike excuse my ignorance, but the txtbox is has runat set to server, so isn't the function called on server? I am calling this one the same way I am other javascript functions that work.

Comment: txtbox's runat propery does not have any impact on javascript function. I was asking if javascript function is called when you press any key

Comment: It is Mike... Sorry for not understanding the question.

Comment: Have you tried `var reg = new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9-]");` ?

Comment: That did not work in debug mode. I am thinking it is the regex.

Comment: Sorry fellas that code worked. Just for whatever reason the changes to the Javascript didn't take affect til the following day.